# react navigation back button back to spalsh screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to use react navigation in react native project but when I use this code in header it shows some back button in every screen and when I click on this it goes back to the splash screen. How to use react navigation with check first splash and then go to stack home and show back button in any screen.its very confuse me.

```js
const TabNav=createBottomTabNavigator({
        Notification:{
            screen:Notif,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
                title:'',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
                    return (
                        <IconIonicons
                            name='ios-notifications'
                            size={40}
                            color={tintColor}
                        />
                    );
                },
                tabBarOptions: {
                    activeTintColor: '#000',
                }
            })
        },

        Home:{
            screen:Home3,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
                title:'',

                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
                    return (
                        <Image style={{ width: 40, height: 40,marginTop:'20%' }} source={Home}/>
                    );
                }

            })
        },
        User:{
            screen:ProfileScreen,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
                title:'',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
                    return (
                        <IconIonicons
                            name='ios-person'
                            size={40}
                            color={tintColor}
                        />
                    );
                },
                tabBarOptions: {
                    activeTintColor: '#000',
                }
            })

        },



    },
    {
        initialRouteName:"Home"
    },{
        header: null,
        headerMode: 'none',
    }
)

const StackHome = createStackNavigator({
    Tabs:{
        screen:TabNav
    },
    CardView:{
        screen:CardView,
    },
    Thumb:{
        screen:Thumb,
    },  Item:{
        screen:Item,
    },  Product:{
        screen:ProductScreen,
    },  Festivals:{
        screen:Festivals,
    } ,  Review:{
        screen:Review,
    } ,  Movie:{
        screen:Movie,
    } ,  Naghd:{
        screen:Naghd,

    } ,  Advertisment:{
        screen:Advertisment,
    } ,  Advertis:{
        screen:Advertis,
    },  CreateAd:{
        screen:CreateAd,
    },  Insta:{
        screen:Insta,
    },  Test:{
        screen:Test,
    },  ForoshRah:{
        screen:ForoshRah,
    },  Home2:{
        screen:Home2,
    },  Login:{
        screen:Login,
    },  Elan:{
        screen:Elan,
    },  Sabtenam:{
        screen:Sabtenam,
    },  sponser:{
        screen:sponsor,
    },Splash:{
        screen:Spalsh
    },Products:{
        screen:Products
    },
        initialRouteName : 'Home',
},{

    headerMode:'none',
        navigationOptions: {

            header: (props) => <ImageHeader {...props} />,

        }
    }

)

const RootNav = createStackNavigator({
    StackHome:{
      screen:StackHome
    },
    Splash:{
        screen:Spalsh
    },Login:{
        screen:Login
    },
},{
        initialRouteName : 'Splash',
        header: null,
});
```

Comment: Don't ```navigation.push``` from your splash (Spalsh?) screen. Use ```navigation.replace```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SwitchNavigator of React Navigation. As the SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away.

Kindly refer this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html

```
Remove the **Splash** Screen from your **StackHome** StackNavigator
Alter your **RootNav** with Switch Navigator like below

// Uses SwitchNavigator
const RootNav = createSwitchNavigator({
    StackHome:{
      screen: StackHome
    },
    Splash:{
        screen: Splash
    },Login:{
        screen: Login
    },
},{
        initialRouteName : 'Splash'
});
```

Your StackHome consist of some stack navigators screens, you can set the navigation options from there itself to set the image in the header. You can set like below.

```
const StackHome = createStackNavigator({
    CardView:{
        screen: CardView,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerTitleStyle: { flex: 1, fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: 15, color: '#FFFFFF', fontFamily: 'DroidSans-Bold' },
            headerTintColor: "#2662b2",
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "#05BFFF",
            },
            headerRight:(<View><NotificationComponent navigation={navigation}/></View>)            
        })
    },
    Thumb:{
        screen: Thumb,
    },  Item:{
        screen: Item,
    }
});
```

Comment: tanks that ok but now show some header in bottom of main header!!!! @Jeeva

Comment: Where do you need to show the header. Main header in the sense, is that your **StackHome** header

Comment: i want to use image in home page header how to use in this rout? @Jeeva

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can use navigation options in stack navigator to set the image in the header

Comment: I use this but not show any image in header have you any suggestion ? @Jeeva